# Issue creating CSS shape

Tags: html, css

I want to create a shape like this but the hollow goes in the bottom. what can I do?

[image]

```
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 100px;
  border: 50px solid #1abc9c;
  border-top: 0 solid;
  border-bottom: 35px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) 10ms;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) 10ms;
  -o-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) 10ms;
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) 10ms;
  -webkit-transform:   translateX(21px) ;
  transform:   translateX(21px) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few lines of CSS will achieve this

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border: 25px solid green;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  margin-right:75px;
}
div:after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
Some content<br>Something
```

Answer (score 4):

make it easy

```
 .ribbon {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 100px;
  border: 50px solid #1abc9c;
  border-top: 0 solid;
  border-bottom: 35px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
}
```

```css
.ribbon {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 100px;
  border: 50px solid #1abc9c;
  border-top: 0 solid;
  border-bottom: 35px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon"></div>
```

Comment: The other answer has the shape you asked ! is that what you wanted ?